# How to avoid concurrent writes to a row using Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, transactions, thread-safety, slick

I have the following table:

`case class Project(id: Int, name: String, locked: Boolean)`

Users can request some processing to be done on the project - but I'd like to make sure only one processing job is being run on the project at a time.

My way right now is to set `locked = true` on the project whenever a job begins, and if a user (malicious or otherwise) tries to start a second job while `locked = true`, it should check if `locked` is already true, and if so, it should respond with an error message saying 'please wait' or such.

I think I need to do this using transactions, so race conditions / concurrent requests wouldn't work, and a malicious user wouldn't be able to send concurrent requests and have multiple jobs start because all saw `locked = false` (as they started simultaneously)

How can I do this with Slick? My current attempt looks like this:

```
def lock(id: Long): Future[Int] = {
        val select = (for {p <- projects if p.id === id && p.locked === false} yield l.locked)
        val q = select.update(true).transactionally //attempting to use transactions
        db.run(q)
    }
```

I believe `db.run` will return the number of rows which were updated, and if `p.locked === false` condition fails, then the number of rows updated will be 0, and I could use that to determine if project was successfully locked. And the `.transactionally` should perhaps make this run in transactions so concurrent requests won't be an issue.

Are my assumptions / reasoning here correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You mean `.update(true)`, right? But then it should work. Maybe use a timestamp instead of a boolean, so that you can timeout if the process dies before it can unlock again.

Comment: @Thilo good catch, yes, I meant true. If you're sure, feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept :). I'm handling timeouts elsewhere so its fine.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `.transactionally` here depends on which database you are using.

Without specifying anything else, in this way you are using the default isolation level for a transaction offered by you db, that for example, if you use Postgres, the level will be `READ COMMITTED`, that means that given two concurrent transactions, one can see the data committed from the other before it ends.

I suggest to you to specify always the isolation level with `.transactionally.withTransactionIsolation(transactionLevel)` to avoid concurrency problems

Comment: I'm using postgres. Any chance you could tell me which transactionIsolation level I'd need for the situation I've described here? E.g it talks about non-repeatable reads and phantom reads, I'm not sure what these mean specifically and don't have time to read up on them.